# How to Detect USB Cable Connection in iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, usb, eaaccessory

I Would like to know whether the USB cable connected to my iPhone or not in my app.
I have researched a lot, i found one solution using the cable connection using charging level/charge detection. but it is not helpful to me.

How to detect USB using EAAccessory?

Thanks,
Anand

Answer (score 0):

try this code using EAAccessoryManager.
it gives notification when an accessory connects or disconnects.

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] registerForLocalNotifications];
NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[notificationCenter addObserver:self
                       selector:@selector(accessoryDidConnect:)
                           name:EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification
                         object:nil];
[notificationCenter addObserver:self
                       selector:@selector(accessoryDidDisconnect:)
                           name:EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification
                         object:nil];
```

Comment: @Anand have you checked IOKit linked here : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/USBBook/USBIntro/USBIntro.html

Comment: How is it possible, to import this library? because no one information